# git return filtered repo to original parent

Tags: git

I want to reverse a git filter-branch and want to know the best way to do this.

Originally I had a repo like this :

```
A
  p
  q
  r
```

I then made q its own repo so that I had this:

```
A
  p
  r  
Q
```

Now, many commits later, I want to reverse that operation to return q to its original parent A.  How can I get Q back to A.q and keep all history?

Answer (score 0):

A few approaches come to mind. I recommend trying these in a clone of the repository to make changing your mind & trying something else trivial. (Though even if you accidentally did it in your only copy, recovery using the reflog and `git reset` ought to be possible).

1. `git subtree`, without `--squash`. This will probably do something close enough to what you want. The command would be (inside A) something like `git subtree add -P q git://user@host/path/Q.git master`. A will still be fast-forwardable.
2. If you want to customize it more, you can use [subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) (which I'm pretty sure git-subtree uses internally). A will still be fast-forwardable.
3. git-filter-branch can do basically anything, no reason it can't merge repositories. You could (for example) pull Q into a branch of A, then filter-branch it to move it all under the q subdirectory, then merge it to master (with `--allow-unrelated-histories`). That'll change all the commit IDs for Q, but not A. Or you could use commit, etc. filters to put the commits together into a history however you'd like (which of course will change a lot of commit IDs, so unless very careful, A will *not* be fast-forwardable).

PS: While questions about programs running on Unix/Linux systems are OK here, there is a lot more expertise about git (and other development tools) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). It's up to you, but I'd personally ask git questions over there, as I think you'll get quicker and quite possibly better answers on SO.